# Is this way to build basic user authentication in React correct?

Tags: reactjs, authentication

This is largely a theoretical question.
I was wondering if this would be considered to be a correct approach or there might be a better route.
Basically just updating the state of the root (App.js) React component based on whether such user exists in the database (and then displaying appropriate components through React Router). This is instead of using Express-Session package for Node, for example. Is this enough for user authentication?

Comment: Somewhat depends on complexity of the app and what needs to be exposed in both conditions and how much you need to re-render or lazy load

Comment: you could look for React Role-based access control: here an example https://github.com/NemerSahli/React-Role-Based-Access-Control